# How to externally control timeline in an Edge Animate composition

Tags: javascript, html, adobe-edge

How do I talk or communicate to an Edge Animate composition via the html page within which it is embedded or via an external js file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a the main timeline, it'd be this from the html page or js file:

```
AdobeEdge.getComposition("EDGE-558482807").getStage().play(12);
```

For a nested symbol, it'd be this from the html page or js file:

```
AdobeEdge.getComposition("EDGE-558482807").getStage().getSymbol("elephant").play(25);
```

You're welcome.  :)